# Is there an Apache module to authenticate against a non-trivial postgresql query?

Tags: django, apache, authentication

I have a Django web app that I would like to use in a single-sign-on solution for a number of remote apps that use Apache authentication.

I can see [how to authenticate Apache from a local Django instance](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/apache-auth/) and [an old Apache module](http://www.giuseppetanzilli.it/mod_auth_pgsql2/) for doing basic queries off postgresql (but without the syntax support to phrase queries with joins to check Django group permissions)

Any suggestions?

I would like to avoid having to switch to using a directory service in the short term (e.g. ActiveDirectory, LDAP) if possible.

.M.

EDIT: Also found mod_auth_external

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following should work for you.

http://www.openfusion.com.au/labs/mod_auth_tkt/

You can use the apache module to hit a specific view in your Django app to generate a ticket for valid users. Then all the other applications can do basic authentication against Django via a URL.

This gives you SSO using the Django user database for legacy apps using HTTP basic authentication.